# Why moment js gives different milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I getting error of different millisecond of same date using moment js.

I am getting data from server (`'-2208988800000'`). I converted the value in `'DD-MMM-YYYY'`. Now I want again same millisecond, why I am getting different milliseconds of same date? Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/1QoWLoFqkNAe2ebZ0V01?p=preview

I have two console `x1` and `x2`. They are different, why?

```js
var x = '-2208988800000'
var d = new Date(moment(new Date(parseInt(x)).toUTCString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
console.log(d)
var x2 = moment(new Date(d).toUTCString()).format('x');
console.log(x2)
// why x1 and x2 is different
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you format the date to `DD-MMM-YYYY` you're losing hours and minutes, that's part of the reason

Try updating your code to

```js
var d = new Date(moment(new Date(parseInt(x)).toUTCString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

and you will get a timestamp that is closer

Answer (score 6):

You've got a terrible amount of manipulation back and forth between moment objects, date objects, and strings.  It's unclear what you actually want to accomplish, but none of that should be necessary.

As to the result, the first call to the date constructor is getting the string value `'31-Dec-1899'`, and thus you can reduce the example to:

```
var d = new Date('31-Dec-1899');
console.log(+d);
```

This will give different results depending on what browser you're running (because the implementation of parsing by the date object is implementation dependent when not in a standard format), and it will vary by time zone where the code is run (because it's assumed the value is in terms of local time).

For me, running in Chrome 70 on Windows 10, in the US Pacific time zone, this logs `-2209046400000`.  You may get different results.

In general, don't do so much manipulation.  Most functions you could want are built in to Moment.  Any time you find yourself converting to strings and back to objects, or using the `Date` constructor, you're probably introducing bugs.

Comment: so what is best was to implement DOB

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I will explain more one sec .Actually I am getting long value from server to display DOB(date of birth) in DD-MMM-YYYY format .user have option to edit the date of birth and send to server same in long or millisecond.if there is no change than user should send same value what is got from server

Comment: At this point, you should probably ask a new question.  Search the [tag:momentjs] tag first, and read through the [guides](http://momentjs.com/guides/) and [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) on the Moment.js website.

Comment: Since it appears you're new here, please also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks, and welcome!